# What does it mean that functions can be used as inputs or be returned from other functions?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming

What is the meaning of this statement in functional programming:

> functions can be used as inputs or be returned as outputs from other functions"

We can also use functions as an input in simple programming. For example:

```
public int getaddition(int a,int b)  {
    return a+b;
}
```

We can call this as:

```
getaddition(getFirstNumber(),getSecondNumber())
```

Can anyone please explain this statement? I am not really getting this definition.

**Edit - Thanks for all the answers. I got my answer but I have one more confusion with this statement regarding functional programming -**

> It Always returns the same output for a given input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int getaddition(int a,int b)
^^^             ^^^   ^^^
```

Here the inputs and the output of `getaddition` are simple integers.

`getaddition(getFirstNumber(),getSecondNumber())` does not pass functions to `getaddition`, it passes the result of calling a function, which is just a number.

What the quote refers to is the ability to pass around functions themselves as values. For example, in JavaScript you can filter an array of values:

```js
const numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 99, 42, 78, 15, 14, 13 ];
const evens = numbers.filter(function (x) { return x % 2 == 0; });
console.log(evens);
```

`.filter` takes a function as an argument. It calls this function repeatedly to determine which elements to keep.

Answer (score 4):

Your code snippet doesn't demonstrate the "functions can be used as inputs or be returned as outputs from other functions" statement. Your `getaddition` method accepts `int` parameters and returns an `int`. You are passing to it the `int` values returned by other method calls, you are not passing to it any functions.

Passing a function as an input to a method means passing an instance of a class that implements some functional interface.

For example:

```
public static int applyOperation(BinaryOperator<Integer> op,int a,int b)  {
    return op.apply (a, b);
}
```

You can pass to that method a function that performs addition:

```
int result = applyOperation ((a,b) -> a + b, 4, 5);
```

and the result would be 9.

You can also pass to that method a function that performs multiplication:

```
int result = applyOperation ((a,b )-> a * b, 4, 5);
```

and the result would be 20.

Returning a function from a method means that the return type of the method would be some functional interface.

For example, here's a method that returns a functional interface that performs addition:

```
public static BinaryOperator<Integer> addition() {
    return (a,b) -> a + b;
}
```

You can pass that function to the previously defined method:

```
int result = applyOperation (addition(), 4, 5)
```

Comment: May I suggest renaming `addition()` to `getOperation()` and having it take either `"+"` or `"*"` and return a function to add or multiply (or throw an exception for any other input). That would still be pretty straightforward and would really demonstrate returning a function, I think.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the statement is about one important characteristic of FP: [Higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function#Scala).

In the particular aspect of function can be passed as parameter, I want to sample it in Java (as the language of your example). Let's take the `Collections.sort` as an example, suppose we want to sort a list of `People` object with a custom comparator, prior to Java8, a `Comparator` object has to be passed.

```
       Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<People>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(People o1, People o2) {
                return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
            }
        });
```

The code doesn't look elegant, what we want to pass is the behavior, i.e. `o1.name.compareTo(o2.name)`, not an object. But as a boundary of OOP, we can only pass the object, so, object wrapper is a workaround to pass the behavior. This's is improved in Java8, where we can pass a behavior:

```
       public int comparePerson(People o1, People o2) {
                return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
            }
       Collections.sort(list, comparePerson);
```

In the example, we pass a function as parameter to `Collections.sort`. We can even pass an "anonymous" function, AKA lambda.

```
Collections.sort(list, (o1, o2) -> o1.name.compareTo(o2.name));
```

Ps: At the end, Java isn't a FPL dispite Java 8 improvement. One easy example it that every parameters has to be declared as some "type", e.g. `Comparator` or `BiFunction`. The name function type or `FunctionalInterface` make it sound like a function. It's not indeed. Interface is a blueprint of an object behavior. Briefly, unlike object, function is not first class citicen in Java.
Look at Scala, you can declare a function param as `(String, String) => Int`, a pure function token.

Answer (score 2):

In Functional Programming, functions are treated just like any other value. Which means they can be passed as arguments and also returned from methods.

For example, the following method accepts a function and returns another function that multiplies the result returned by the input function:

```
public Function<Integer, Integer> multiply2(Function<Integer, Integer> function) {
    return i -> function.apply(i) * 2;
}
```

Keep in mind that those calculations are not actually performed. It's just an expression of our will.

If you want an action to happen, you need to call its method explicitly:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> function = multiply2(i -> i + 1);
function.apply(42);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty clear from the other answers that the method you've shown is not a [*higher order function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) as it doesn't take a function nor return one.

Moving to your question:

What is the meaning of this statement in functional programming?

> functions can be used as inputs or be returned as outputs from other
>   functions

As the Java language supports [first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function). We say that first-class functions are functions treated as objects themselves, meaning we can pass a function as a parameter to another function, return a function from a function, store a function in a variable, or store them in data-structures.

Right, this might sound vague; so in Java terms what does this exactly mean?

it simply means if a method has any [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) as its parameter or return value e.g. `Function<T, R>`, `Predicate<T>`, `Supplier<T>` et al then that method is a [*higher order function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) and that's what the above quote is referring to.